# What does your bit.ly username and password become when you login using Twitter?

Tags: api, twitter, bitly

I use a Twitter account to login to bit.ly at the sign in screen.

I've also signed up to use their authentication because I want to use node.js to generate shortened links using the [node-bitlyapi module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-bitlyapi).

The example code asks for a username and password:

```
var BitlyAPI = require("node-bitlyapi");
var Bitly = new BitlyAPI({
   // both of these values have been retrieved by Registering a Bitly OAuth app.
   client_id: "", 
   client_secret: ""
});

var username="" // Added Twitter Username;
var password="" // Added Twitter Password;

Bitly.authenticate(username, password, function(err, access_token) {
   // Returns err if there was one, or an access token if here wasn't:

   console.log('err: ' + err);
   console.log('access_token: ' + access_token);
});
```

When I run the code above I get the following output which doesn't give me alot to go on since there isn't an error and there isn't an access_token:

```
Basic MWExMGM0ZWFjZTFiZDg4Y2NiQjAyODE5OWIyOWRmNGUyMzUxZGU1NzowZDc5ODY1NzMwZTk2N2E3N2JiZDZmY2I5YmMyZDI0ZjRiOWZ2ZjAz
err: null
access_token: undefined
```

This leads me to believe that it isn't authenticating and that I need some other sort of username and password to work with the API.

Comment: I have another account and it uses just a username and password (not a Twitter or a Facebook login), and it seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I entered my email address in on the site, and requested to reset my password.  Then after receiving the email and resetting my password I noticed that I was able to use the email address on the account to login instead of Twitter.  When I used my email address and what the password was reset to, I was able to obtain an access token.